# Spring Data MongoDB 1.10.13 and Mongo 3.4

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to upgrade from Mongo 3.2 to Mongo 3.4. I updated my POM to use the latest Spring Data MongoDB (1.10.13) and while doing so, I noticed Spring Data MongoDB is still being compiled/depended on the old MongoDB Java driver (2.14.3). Since my project is dependent on the Spring Data MongoDB and MongoDB 3.4 driver, I ended up having 2 MongoDB drivers in my libs, which seems to have caused problems.

I ended up adding an exclusion in my POM. Is this the right way to go? How should I override the old MongoDB driver which originates from Spring Data MongoDB 1.10?

This is what my POM looks like:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.13.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
         <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
         </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```